# Swift - SKActions functions not working, is it possible that swift changed some functions resulting in error?

Tags: ios, swift

I am following a tutorial series on youtube and have come across a problem with SpriteKit's SKActions. In the tutorial there is a "ground" in the middle of the screen and a person running constantly. The player taps to flip the person to the other side and avoid objects.

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

What is happening is when I tap again the player should go back to his original position, but instead it flips the player but doesn't actually switch the direction of the position. This results in this:

[image]

It seems that many people following the tutorial have this problem. I have been through the code many times and its exact, and have even downloaded his repository and ran it, and the same problem arises.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 159.0/255.0, green: 201.0/255.0, blue: 244.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    movingGround = MovingGround(size: CGSizeMake(view.frame.width, GROUND_HEIGHT))

    movingGround.position = CGPointMake(0, view.frame.size.height / 2)
    addChild(movingGround)

    hero = Hero()
    hero.position = CGPointMake(70, movingGround.position.y + movingGround.frame.size.height / 2 + hero.frame.size.height / 2)
    addChild(hero)

    hero.breathe()
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    hero.stop()
    hero.flip()
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
}
```

Flip function:

```
func flip() {
    isUpsideDown = !isUpsideDown

    var scale: CGFloat!

    if isUpsideDown {
        scale = -1.0
    } else {
        scale = 1.0
    }

    let translate = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: scale * (size.height + GROUND_HEIGHT), duration: 0.1)
    let flip = SKAction.scaleYTo(scale, duration: 0.1)

    runAction(translate)
    runAction(flip)

}
```

I can provide more code if necessary, but this is all that should be relevant.

Now the real question is why the hell isn't this working? Why would it work on his computer and not mine? My only thinking is that SWIFT has changed since he released that series a few months ago, and changed the functions in some way that is making this not work correctly?

How should I be doing this? The code makes sense and works for him, and being new to Swift, this isn't making me feel very swift :c

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: if you flip again and again is your hero positioned as on picture 3 or it became lower and lower?

Comment: It flips lower and lower until it is off the screen

Comment: if you delete (size.height + GROUND_HEIGHT) your hero is just standing on his head when you flip?

Comment: so play with (size.height + GROUND_HEIGHT) and I think you're done with this bug

Comment: I don't see another way.. The tutorial is exactly like that, and when I downloaded his source code the same error arised. The scale factor should be switching his position between the two, and the calculation seems right. But when it comes to actually positioning him he goes down the screen

Comment: may be you have negative size.height when your hero is up side down? and then you sum with GROUND_HEIGHT you get negative total result?

Comment: what scaleToY function code is?